# TCPDF: how to install in WAMP without COMPOSER?

Tags: php, wamp, tcpdf

I'm using WAMP and I would need to create PDF from php/html pages.

I had some trouble with DOMPDF since it seems unable to manage tables longer than a page, and I'm considering to use TCPDF.

I saw that I could install TCPDF with COMPOSER but I would prefer,if possible, to avoid a further installation.

Any chances to install TCPDF without composer?

thanks

Comment: TCPDF doesn't have any dependencies, apart from PHP, so it should be relatively easy to do. I think you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) without even coming near Composer, but it doesn't convert HTML to PDF, it is therefore far simpler.

Comment: excellent suggestion KIKO thank you! will have a  butcher's soon, but you mean that I have to use pure PHP? then HTML have to echoed? thanks

Comment: Yes, FPDF is very simple, so don't use it for overly complicated PDF documents. It's useful for things like invoices. You create the PDF file directly with pure PHP, no HTML in between. It can be a bit fiddly doing it that way, but it is fast and simple.